# Binding Firebase onAuth callback to an observable

Tags: firebase, angular, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to bind the callback resulting to an `onAuth()` request in Firebase to an RxJS observable.

```
let auth = Observable.bindCallback(ref.onAuth);
let source = auth();
let subscription = source.subscribe(
    (x) => console.log(x),
    (e) => console.log(e)
);
```

I get the error:

> Cannot read property 'O' of undefined at BoundCallbackObservable.X.Ig [as callbackFunc]

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is the incorrect context callback function executes in. This should fix it:

```javascript
let auth = Observable.bindCallback(ref.onAuth.bind(ref));
```